# Perl file handles - overwrite existing data instead of appending/deleting

Tags: perl, file-handling

```
cat -E test1.txt
```

output:

```
car$
$
$
```

I want just change "car" with "bike" and remove new/empty lines.

This is working as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(FILE1,"<","./test1.txt"); @araj=<FILE1>; close(FILE1);
open(FILE2,">","./test1.txt");
map {
s@car@bike@; s@^\n@@;
} @araj;
print(FILE2 @araj);
close(FILE2);
```

and

```
cat -E test1.txt
```

output is 100% correct for me:

```
bike$
```

But in above case i am using 2x opening/close file. 
So i am using 2x file handles.
I want to use only **1x** file handle
(it`s for learning purposes, just trying to understand how +> +>> >> are working...).
For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(FILE2,"+<","./test1.txt"); #what file handle should be here? +> , +>> >> .... ?
@araj=<FILE2>;
map {
s@car@bike@; s@^\n@@;
} @araj;
print(FILE2 @araj);
close(FILE2);
```

output is incorrect:

```
car$
$
$
bike$
```

Why this is appending, but no overwriting? When i used others file handles, results are also incorrect, for example empty file... 
Which file handle is used for read-and-overwrite ?

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html

Comment: @ikegami thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why this is appending, but no overwriting?

You have first read all the data until the end of the file. This mean the file position for the next read or write is now after all the data you have read, i.e. at the end of the file. If you want to write data from the beginning of the file you need to change the file position by using [seek](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html):

```
 seek($filehandle,0,0); # position at beginning of file
```

The next data you write will then be written starting with this new file position, i.e. from the beginning of the file. Once you are done you might need to remove any data after the current file position from the file by using [truncate](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) with the current file position you've got with [tell](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html):

```
 truncate($filehandle, tell($filehandle));
```

Or, the whole program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $fh, "+<", "./test1.txt");
my @araj = <$fh>;
for(@araj) {
    s{car}{bike};
    s{^\n}{};
}
seek($fh, 0, 0);           # seek at the beginning of the file
print $fh @araj;
truncate($fh, tell($fh));  # remove everything after current file position
close($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you read file in array the filehandle position is end of the file.
Then you should change filehandle position by `seek` function (set on start of the file) [`perldoc seek`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html).
Next resize you file by `truncate` [`perldoc truncate`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(FILE2,"+<","./test1.txt"); #what file handle should be here? +> , +>> >> .... ?
@araj=<FILE2>;
map {
s@car@bike@; s@^\n@@;
} @araj;

seek(FILE2, 0, 0);
print(FILE2 @araj);
truncate(FILE2, tell(FILE2));

close(FILE2);
```